# Find the range of $f(x)=\log_3(x) +log_x(3)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I have to find the domain of the function $f(x)=\log_3(x) +log_x(3)$. I know that for some functions we differentiate it and check the function in critical points. However, differentiated this but couldn't find the zeroes of $f'(x)$. 
When I graphed it, $[-2,2]$ seems to not be part of the range. Why?

Comment: Do you know the change of base rule for logs?

Comment: Yes, I get $log_3(x)+1/log_3(x)$

Comment: Hint: If $a>0$, then $a+\frac{1}{a} \geq 2$ and if $a<0$, then $a+\frac{1}{a} \leq -2$.

Comment: From $y=x+1/x$, $x^2-yx+1=0$, $D=y^2-4*1*1>0$ so $y^2>4$, and I get the right range. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(x) = \frac {\ln x}{\ln 3} + \frac {\ln 3}{\ln x}$

The function is not defined at $x = 1$ and it is not defined when $x\le 0$

What happens as we approach these points:

$\lim_\limits{x\to 0^+} f(x) = -\infty\\\lim_\limits{x\to 1^-} f(x) = -\infty\\
\lim_\limits{x\to 1^+} f(x) = \infty\\
\lim_\limits{x\to \infty} f(x) = \infty$

What are the critical points?

$\frac {df}{dx} = \frac {1}{x\ln 3} - \frac{\ln 3}{x\ln^2 x} = 0\\
x\ln^2 x = x\ln^2 3\\
\ln x = \pm \ln 3$

you should be careful when dividing through by $x,$ but we have already identified that $x\ne 0$

Plugging into our original equation.

$f(\frac 13) = -2$ is the maximum over the inteval in the domain $(0,1)$

$f(3) = 2$ is the minimum over the interval $(1,\infty)$

$(-\infty,-2)\cup (2,\infty)$

Answer (score 1):

Use the identity $\log_a(b)=\frac{\ln(b)}{\ln(a)}$ and work out the range of $x+\frac{1}{x}$.